# Port for Sending Email for gmail account

Tags: c#

Please can some one help me out whether the correct port for sending email from an gmail account is 25 ,465 or 587. I checked on some forms it says that C# classes does not support sending email using SSL it uses TSL and the port used for TSL is 587. IS it correct? I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail usually works with Port Number 587 in .net Application. 
Check the following Example Code sample

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SmtpClientObject = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

SmtpClientObject.UseDefaultCredentials = false;    
SmtpClientObject.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyUserName@gmail.com", "myPassword");    
SmtpClientObject.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";    
SmtpClientObject.Port = 587;    
SmtpClientObject.EnableSsl = true;    
SmtpClientObject.Send("MyUserName@gmail.com", "YourUserName@gmail.com", "TestSubject", "MessageBody");
```